# how do I change an image by selecting a cell in CollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, collectionview

Currently I am working on a project and my product page is like this 
[image]

Here I am using an **UIImageView** to show the large image and below that I am using a **CollectionView** to scroll a set of images. I want to change the large image accordingly when I click an image from the **CollectionViewCell** . As this is the first time I am using this kind of functionality, I am out of clue. Please anybody give me some suggestion. Thank you.

Comment: use collectionview delegates

Comment: Can you share your code so we can help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If every image is in a separate UICollectionViewCell, use

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                             didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // here you know which item is selected by accessing indexPath.item property, for example:
    let selectedImage = yourImages[indexPath.item]
    bigImageView.image = selectedImage
}
```

method to detect when user selects a collection view item.
In order to use this method you need to conform to `UICollectionViewDelegate` and set `collectionView.delegate = self`