# how to extract json array and use it without tableview

Tags: swift

Suppose I got a **JSON** response like this one:

```
{
"product_list" =     (
            {
        "product_id" = 33;
        "product_image" =             (
        );
        "product_sku" = asdasd;
        "product_title" = "Product 1";
    },
            {
        "product_id" = 58;
        "product_image" =             (
        );
        "product_sku" = kkkk222;
        "product_title" = p1;
    },
            {
        "product_id" = 119;
        "product_image" =             (
        );
        "product_sku" = 123456;
        "product_title" = product;
    },
            {
        "product_id" = 120;
        "product_image" =             (
        );
        "product_sku" = 456789;
        "product_title" = "product 3";
    }
);
  "xxx_api" = "product_information";
}
```

and this is how I use **cellForRowAt indexPath** to populate **Cell** of a table.

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: SpecificCatagoryBodyCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SpecificCatagoryBodyCell") as! SpecificCatagoryBodyCell

    let categoryList = sCategory[indexPath.row]
    cell.product_id.text = String(categoryList.product_id)    
    cell.sCategoryName.text = categoryList.product_title

    let profileImage = categoryList.product_image
    SDWebImageManager.shared().downloadImage(with: profileImage, options: [], progress: nil) { downloadedImage, error, cacheType, isDownloaded, url in
            cell.sCategoryImage.image = downloadedImage
        }

    return cell
}
```

Everything is fine if I want to populate **Cell** of **tableView** . Problem is sometimes I need to use different data to make any call, suppose here I need the **product_id** from **JSON** response and use that respective number to make a call. How can I extract the number outside **tableView** index wise , may be extract it in a function, store it in a variable and use it . Here is the visual I am providing to better understand . In the first picture you can see there are **Cell** in the table

[image]

When I tap on a **Cell** It goes to different **ViewController** , so I want when I tap on the **Cell** it passes **product_id** of the respective  **cell** and use that **product_id** to make another **post** call to show the details of the product. Here is the product details page below.

[image]

Hope that make sense. I am happy to provide more details if you need it. Many many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that I am missing some details here, but...

Your "problem" is that you can have more than one occurrence of `categoryList` items...which is why you are using a `UITableView` in the first place I guess.

In your `UITableView` the solution to "which element should I show now", is handed to you by `cellForRowAt`. In that function, all you do is pick the `JSON` item matching the cell you are about to populate now.

You do so by calling:

```
let categoryList = sCategory[indexPath.row]
```

And I assume that `sCategory` is an array of `categoryList` items where you then ask for the one matching `indexPath.row`.

So, if you would like to use `product_id` from a specific product in your `sCategory` array, you'd need to know *which* product in your array to use.

This can be done in several ways.

1. **You already know which index to use**

   In that case a simple method to give you the `product_id` could look like this:

   ```
   func productId(fromIndex index: Int) -> Int? {
       guard sCategory.count > index else { //just a check to make sure the index actually exists in your collection
           return nil
       }
       return sCategory[index].product_id
   }
   ```

   Used like this:

   ```
   if let productId = productId(fromIndex: someIndexYouAlreadyKnow) {
        //You're in business :)
   }
   ```
2. **You don't know which index to use**

   in that case you need to know that to look for, lets say you know the `product_title` and that `product_title` is unique.

   You could then write a function like this:

   ```
   func productId(forTitle productTitle: String) -> Int? {
       let candidates = sCategory.filter { $0.product_title == productTitle}
       guard candidates.count == 1 else { //assure that we have exactly one hit
           return nil
       }
       return candidates.first!.product_id
   }
   ```

   Which you could use like this:

   ```
   if let productId = productId(forTitle: "Product 1") {
        //You're in business :)
   }
   ```

### Update (after having seen your updated question)

You say

> so I want when I tap on the Cell it passes product_id of the respective cell and use that product_id to make another post call to show the details of the product.

I can see that you have already asked this question: [how do I change an image by selecting a cell in CollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41163222/how-do-i-change-an-image-by-selecting-a-cell-in-collectionview)

And the answer here is pretty much the same :)

A `UITableView` has a `UITableViewDelegate` just like the `UICollectionView` has a `UICollectionViewDelegate`. One of the methods that a `UITableViewDelegate` can chose to implement is [tableView(_:didSelectRowAt:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614877-tableview), which even gives you the `indexPath` of the selected row.

So if you have the method `productId(fromIndex: )` that I suggested earlier you could do something along the lines of

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let productId = productId(fromIndex: indexPath.row) {
        //you now have the productId matching the selected row, use that for you further adventures :)
    }
}
```

Hope that helps you.

Comment: I really appreciate your effort , its really generous. Please help me a bit more , I am struggling . I really eager to learn from you guys. I have updated the question , please inform me if you need any more details.

Comment: yes it was relatively simple , I got my answer. Thank you so much for your kind reply. I did a static project earlier , I took the idea from there, of course your answers helped me to get the idea as well. i an working with **json** for the very first time and my company has handled me a massive project, i am working alone here as an iOS developer with no help from colleagues. Therefore sometimes I ask from StackOverFlow. If someone guided me about the issue it was relatively simple.

Comment: it's easy...when you know how to do it :) Glad you got it working

Answer (score 0):

finally I got the solution like this

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if( segue.identifier == "productList_to_detail" ) {

        let VC1 = segue.destination as! ShopItemVC
          if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let productIdToGet = sCategory[indexPath.row]
                VC1.product_id = productIdToGet.product_id
            }
        }
    }
```